# How do I put my computer username in a filepath of my VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

Edited for clarity. I get an error "Expected: List separator or (" on line 6/7 where the filepath is and the error highlights the "C". I've tried different combinations of "" with no success.

```
Public Function UserName()
UserName = Environ$("UserName")
End Function

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Users\ & Username() & \Desktop\HOBP_14.accdb;Mode=Share" _
    , _
    " Deny Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OL" _
    , _
    "EDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet" _
    , _
    " OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Loc" _
    , _
    "ale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False" _
    ), Destination:=Range("$F$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdTable
    .CommandText = Array("Sum_FTE_SG")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .SourceDataFile = "C:\Users\" & Username() & "\Desktop\HOBP_14.accdb"
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_HOBP_14.accdb"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: When concatenating strings to build up a valid path, you need to check that you have backslash ("\") characters added as required to separate the various parts of the path.

Comment: most likely error is that yo have not ensured that `filePath` ends in a separator `"\"` and also you would need to add the same separator/backslash *after* `Environ("username")`, like: `filepath & "\" & Environ("username") & "\" & filename`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby

Comment: For maximum portability when constructing paths, instead of hard coding "\" everywhere you can use Excel's `Application.PathSeparator` property, which will evaluate to "\" in this case.

Comment: If your just saving in special folders (e.g. Desktop), then better off using this: `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" & <filename>`. This also is compatible with any OS version.

Comment: I'm getting a "Compile Error, Expected: list separator or )"

Comment: And the error points to the "C" in the filepath:
    Source=C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\HOBP_14.accdb

Answer (score 0):

The most likely error is missing path separator(s), aka backslash: `"\"`.

I can't see how you've constructed `filePath` variable, but you could always add something like this immediately after the assignment:

```
filePath = IIF(right(filePath,1) = "\", filePath, filePath & "\")
```

ANd likewise, you need to ensure that the backslash *after* your username, so:

```
filepath & Environ("username") & "\" & filename
```

Or in your case where you have a function:

```
filepath & UserName() & "\" & filename
```

I also notice some bad string concatenation in your `Source:=` argument. The "Data Source" you're passing is a string literal, so the presumed call to your `UserName()` function is not interpreted as a function call, but as part of the string itself.  You can escape that with quotes:

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Users\" & UserName() & "\Desktop\HOBP_14.accdb;Mode=Share" _
```

Or my preferred way to resolve it would be to use a variable to represent the data source, earlier in the code, and use that *eveyrwhere* you need to refer to that data source (there are two places in this code):

```
Dim dataSource As String

dataSource = "C:\Users\" & UserName() & "\Desktop\HOBP_14.accdb"

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & dataSource & ";Mode=Share" _
    , _
    " Deny Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OL" _
    , _
    "EDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet" _
    , _
    " OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Loc" _
    , _
    "ale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False" _
    ), Destination:=Range("$F$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdTable
    .CommandText = Array("Sum_FTE_SG")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .SourceDataFile = dataSource             '##### ALSO CHANGED THIS LINE #####
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_HOBP_14.accdb"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With
```

Comment: @pnuts [filepath] TBH that seems like a throwaway tag which is why I removed it initially, seems like one of those random tags that people just make up. I guess it might be useful somehow so I will add it back in.

Comment: still not working...I get an "expected: list separator or (" prompt and it highlights the "C" at the beginning of my filepath.

Comment: Can you revise your Question to include a little more of your code -- make sure it's the code you're *currently using* which is causing the error, and indicate specifically which line it's raising the error on?  I'm sure I can see what's wrong if I can see the code.

Comment: Which "C" is highlighted?  YOu have obvious errors with bad string concatenation in your `Source:=`, but the code executes without raising any compile errors when I try to run it.

Comment: The C on line 5 "Data Source=C:\Users\" gets highlighted when I try to use "" marks. When I don't use any "" marks the database tries to find the filepath "C:\Users\ & Username() & \Desktop\HOBP_14.accdb" without replacing the Username() with my computers username.

Comment: Yeah that's an obvious problem you have bad string concatenation. and that is treated as a literal string, not a call to that function.  I'll put an example in my answer that should fix that.

Comment: Cheers! If this has helped or solved your problem, do consider upvoting or "Accepting" the answer :)